# WPF: custom TabControl - TabItem Header gets lost

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I'm using this sample to customize a TabControl:

> TabControlStyle - Part Three.zip:
>   https://web.archive.org/web/20160319001935/http://www.blogs.intuidev.com/file.axd?file=2010%2f2%2fTabControlStyle+-+Part+Three.zip

from url:

> https://web.archive.org/web/20160319001935/http://www.blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/02/10/TabControlStyling_PartThree.aspx

now if you run and select sample 5 (TabControl_5_ScrollableTabPanel) you will see that everything works fine. Opening the popup works also.

However when **adding a new tabitem with a custom header and opening the popup on the right** makes that the tabitem's header gets reset to a minimum size and the content is lost.

In the sample in TabControl_5_ScrollableTabPanel.xaml I've just added an extra tabitem between the existing Tab 2 and Tab 3:

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Red" />
        <TextBlock Text="Test" />
      </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
  </TabItem>
```

I've seen that after UIElement.Measure() the DesiredSize is incorrect for this tab with custom header. 
In the ScrollableTabPanel I've tried to change the **MeasureOverride** method so that it does an extra check for the header:

```
      //Loop through all child controls ...
  foreach (UIElement uieChild in this.InternalChildren)
  {
    // test:
    TabItem uieChildTabItem = uieChild as TabItem;
    if (uieChildTabItem != null && uieChildTabItem.HasHeader && uieChildTabItem.Header != null)
    {
      UIElement uieChildHeader = uieChildTabItem.Header as UIElement;
      if (uieChildHeader != null)
      {
        uieChildHeader.Measure(availableSize);
        resultSize.Width += uieChildHeader.DesiredSize.Width;
      }
    }
  // ...
```

...but it still doesn't bring the header back to its original size, showing its content.

Does anyone see where it goes wrong and why my solution doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to declare the TabItem as below :

```
<TabItem Header="TabTest">
            <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Red" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Test" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>               
        </TabItem>
```

As per this Tab Panel implementation, it directly binds the TabItem's header to the context menu item header in the popup. This creates problem if you trying to give some UI element to tab item header instead of string, and this Tab Panel trying to host same UI element twice in a visual tree. Since it is not allowed , it removed the UI element from TabItem's header and shows only in the menu item's header.